# how to pass query params for a delete request in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I need to pass a query param in my request url. How do i do that in Robotframework.
Note - i want to pass a key value param in which key='mykey' and value= {'a':1, 'b':2}

let say my request url should be something like this - [https://10.245.14.123:52437/cisco/voiceService/mykey={'a':1](https://10.245.14.123:52437/cisco/voiceService/mykey=%7B%27a%27:1), 'b':2}

so how to perform this in robotframework

Comment: Please edit your question because it is unreadable.

Comment: So this is the edited question and quite clear------
I am trying to send a GET on Session for a url.
I want unicode characters in my url, Lets say for example--
I need my request url as - https://google.com/{abc}
so when i try to send this the '{' converted to '%7B'.
so any suggestions how to pass special characters or unicodes in my url?

Thanks,
Anup